Texture paint mode poor brush strokes quality
When I draw in Texture paint mode in 3d editor my brush has poor quality strokes - no anti-aliasing, black artifacts around the stroke. But when draw in UV Image edit - everything is fine, strokes are nice and smooth. Is there anything I don't know about Texture paint mode? There is not anti-aliasing option in Texture paint mode, it's only available in UV Image edit. But drawing in 2d is so inaccurate compared to drawing right on a 3d model. No matter what I tweak in Texture paint mode I can't make the brush strokes to be clean and smooth. My texture has 4k resolution.


Hi Anna, hard to tell without your file. At least for me, I never had this problem and a quick test showed me my Texture Paint has smooth strokes. If nobody has a good idea for this issue from the screenshot, maybe you can upload your file here: https://blend-exchange.com and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question?

Was the painting smooth prior to this at any point in time? Is this the first time you are using the paint mode in Blender, or could it be related to a driver issue on the AMD side from an update there? You mentioned over on BA that you tried multiple versions of blender, so that means it isn't in the settings of the scene or the tool, and it isn't the model because you said you had the same result on the default cube. If you can upload a mesh object with the image painted this way packed in the file, we can try the same brush on our end to see.

Hi! I tried other software and installed Quixel Mixer just to be sure and the lines are also jagged in there. I guess the problem is that I used brush size 3-4px and I zoomed in onto the model too much to draw small details. When I zoom out, even 2px brush seems to work fine and it's very smooth. Kinda feels like there is a connection between zoom distance and how jagged the stroke is. More zoom = more stroke artifacts.
